# C# stackalloc slower than regular variables?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, unsafe, stackalloc

I have 2 functions implementing uint128 multiplication in 2 different ways: one is using variables, the other using stackalloc "arrays".

**Variable Version**

```
public static UInt128 operator *(UInt128 i, UInt128 j) {

 ulong I0 = i._uint0; ulong I1 = i._uint1; ulong I2 = i._uint2; ulong I3 = i._uint3;
 ulong J0 = j._uint0; ulong J1 = j._uint1; ulong J2 = j._uint2; ulong J3 = j._uint3;
 ulong R0 = 0; ulong R1 = 0; ulong R2 = 0; ulong R3 = 0;

 if (I0 != 0) {
   R0 += I0 * J0;
   R1 += I0 * J1;
   R2 += I0 * J2;
   R3 += I0 * J3;
 }
 if (I1 != 0) {
   R1 += I1 * J0;
   R2 += I1 * J1;
   R3 += I1 * J2;
 }
 if (I2 != 0) {
   R2 += I2 * J0;
   R3 += I2 * J1;
 }
 R3 += I3 * J0;

 R1 += R0 >> 32; R0 &= uint.MaxValue;
 R2 += R1 >> 32; R1 &= uint.MaxValue;
 R3 += R2 >> 32; R2 &= uint.MaxValue;
 R3 &= uint.MaxValue;

 return new UInt128((uint)R3, (uint)R2, (uint)R1, (uint)R0);
}
```

**Stackalloc Version**

The `[0 + 1]`, `[1 + 1]`, etc. are left for clarity only. They will be optimized by C# compiler into constants anyways.

```
public unsafe static UInt128 operator *(UInt128 i, UInt128 j) {

  var I = stackalloc ulong[4];
  var J = stackalloc ulong[4];
  var R = stackalloc ulong[4];

  I[0] = i._uint0; I[1] = i._uint1; I[2] = i._uint2; I[3] = i._uint3;
  J[0] = j._uint0; J[1] = j._uint1; J[2] = j._uint2; J[3] = j._uint3;


  if (I[0] != 0) {
    R[0] += I[0] * J[0];
    R[0 + 1] += I[0] * J[1];
    R[0 + 2] += I[0] * J[2];
    R[0 + 3] += I[0] * J[3];
  }
  if (I[1] != 0) {
    R[1] += I[1] * J[0];
    R[1 + 1] += I[1] * J[1];
    R[1 + 2] += I[1] * J[2];
  }
  if (I[2] != 0) {
    R[2] += I[2] * J[0];
    R[2 + 1] += I[2] * J[1];
  }
  R[3] += I[3] * J[0];


  R[1] += R[0] >> 32; R[0] &= uint.MaxValue;
  R[2] += R[1] >> 32; R[1] &= uint.MaxValue;
  R[3] += R[2] >> 32; R[2] &= uint.MaxValue;
  R[3] &= uint.MaxValue;

  return new UInt128((uint)R[3], (uint)R[2], (uint)R[1], (uint)R[0]);
}
```

For some reason the "variable" version seems to be ~20% faster than the "stackalloc" version on both x86 and x64 (with optimizations) using C# 7.2 compiler running on .NET 4.6.1. Haven't checked the performance on newer/older frameworks but suspect it will be similar, so my question is not specific to 4.6.1 only, as it seems to be generally the case that stackalloc is slower.

Is there any reason that the stackalloc version is slower considering that both version allocate exactly the same amount of memory (`12 * sizeof(ulong)`) and perform exactly the same operations in the same order? I would really prefer to work with arrays via stackalloc instead of variables.

Comment: The "variable" version doesn't use arrays at all, that's my guess to why it's faster. Why would you prefer to use `stackalloc` at all, if not for a performance increase?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Because not all the algorithms will need just 12 variables as in this case, and when you deal with more complex routines, arrays are just so much better.

Comment: So you're balancing between performance and maintainability - the local `ulong` values are also stored on the stack, so you're currently only measuring array access vs local variable access. Perhaps a `struct` could bring the best of both worlds here.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis stackalloc returns not array (I mean not C# array), but pointer to the first "slot" of allocated memory.

Comment: I'd better stop commenting then :)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Thanks for the suggestion regarding a `struct`. I thought about it too, but when I tested it, it was way slower than stackalloc, even though I made it a C# 7.2 `ref struct`, which presumably should have sped things up as it lives on the stack only.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis A version using arrays translated to IL is still 22% shorter than the `stackalloc` version translated to IL.

Comment: This is old, but just for the sake of adding to it: you can fairly test `stackalloc` benefits by copying stackalloc version, removing `unsafe` keyword and changing `stackalloc` into `new`. This will test two array versions of the function, one with stack allocation and one allocating from heap.

Comment: @Iván Hernández the real cost will reveal only if GC kicks in. and i dont know if its the case with returned pointers from stackalloc but arrays have bound checking overhead, if compiler cant optimize it ensuring you never access indexes beyond its length.

Answer (score 2):

[IL from the variable version (simplified)](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgZgAQWAJwK4GNhIKoCSAdsAIwBMAHAN4CwAUEk0hgDYD2RA5kgPoYBLEgAYA3A2YsO3PoJKlxjZm049+Q4OUWSVM9SQTbmifMTJUAFHNxgANCw1IARvetIsrxwBMAlHSWSTPrAwkgAvEhgRoGyGqThztGBweQJWEmSwcgRXkkAvgyF9CZwpABspvJUSOwADgCmaGDA7GhIAFQWhFWUSAL23ea9AFY+SP4SujwEoRECAHTBYkiT0jwAUrNIw4vWy6uqSABKW/v0EgIAZkgWM0gAhBEUCAAsY/7MJ0gA1BF37UhNooJAVzmCkHAAOxIIj1ADulSGFisGh8wnsKJIaIx1mxN1xJx8ilBkjyQA=)

[IL from the array version (simplified)](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgZgAQWAJwK4GNhIKoCSAdsAIwBMAHAN4CwAUEk0hgDYD2RA5kgPoYBLEgAYA3A2YsO3PoJKlxjZm049+Q4OUWSVM9SQTbmifMTJUAFHNxgANCw1IARvetIsrxwBMAlHSWSTPrAwkgAvEhgRoGyGqThztGBweQJWEmSwcgRXkkAvgyF9CYYRBBgAGYApkhwpABspvJUSOwADlVoYMDsaEgAVBaEzZRIAvbD5qMAVj5I/hJIAG5gfQQJqGBYANZgrBxYUqoA2qQAukYrfQBSG8Bbu/vsh7pcpxeLV0gASncPewcjtx3opFgRjsIzgkBAA6YJiJCLa4QqERaZw6xiIqLAQVJAWcGQpAAQgiFAQABY5v5JN8UUgANQRQlQ/pIZGQowFeiLOAAdiQRCqAHcmlMLFYND5hPZJSRpbLrAr8Uq6ZCfIpuZI8kA=)

The array version is using the stack (see L0009 - L004E), but the variable version is just using a register. Although the data fits into the CPU cache, it's still slower than using a CPU register.